# how to retrieve data from model cakephp

Tags: cakephp, date, model

I have a controller function named `updateoos()`, a model for that function `Outofserviceday` and a table named `outofservicedays`. The table has 3 fields - `id`, `userid`, `outofservicedays`.

I want to get the out of service days from today to the last day of month
how to write a function in `Outofserviceday` model with two arguments `today` and `monthedDday` like.

```
function ($today $monthedDday) { }
```

In my controller I get the two dates

```
$today = date("Ymd");
$monthend=date("ymd", strtotime($today));
```

**I edited all my mistakes**

Comment: Reedit Your post, your code doesn't work, there is no separator, name of function...

Comment: Is there any specific reason as of why you are breaking all the CakePHP convention rules? The Model name, table name and field names are all "off".

Comment: actually that is not the correct names, i added just for an example

Comment: if anybody knows plese tel me how toretrive that particular data from the model

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your times to unix timestamp and check the values against your target dates.

Example:

```
$no_service_days = $this-> Outofserviceday->find('all');

$nsd_array = array();

$end_date = strtotime($monthend); // or strtotime('31-01-12');

foreach ($no_service_days as $key => $day) : 
   $record_u_time = strtotime($day['Outofserviceday']['outofservicedays']);
   if($record_u_time < $end_date){
      $nsd_array[] = $day;
   }
endforeach;

pr($nsd_array);
```

This is a loose approach to the technique you should use since your code and naming conventions are honestly pretty confusing.

I don't see a `date` field in your table so I assume it's `outofservicedays` and your `$monthend=date("ymd", strtotime($today));` doesn't appear to be a date in the future or past.